# PHPStorm 9 colors

Tags: phpstorm

I noticed that if I'm editing a page with just HTML, but save the page as .php (there is no PHP in the page), there are no code hint colors.  If I resave to .html, there are.  Might there be a way to show the colors?

See below..

**with PHP extension:**

[image]

**with HTML extension:**

[image]

Comment: It does this by default. Try removing all your plugins to see if that fixes it. If that doesn't fix, do a re-install.

Comment: thanks.  What is the default?  With the colors or like what's happening to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug introduced in recent 9.0.1 version.

The idea was to treat double extensions in file name and setup outer language automatically. What this means: in ordinary `.php` file all text outside PHP tags is treated as HTML/Plain Text .. but in files like `file.js.php` the outer language (text outside PHP tags) is most likely will be JavaScript instead of HTML. To have it as JavaScript (syntax highlighting and code completion/analysis) you would need to manually set it up to JavaScript on per file/directory basis.

So devs decided (after many votes in corresponding ticket) to automate this task. Unfortunately they did not checked well enough how it will work with other double extensions (`.inc.php` or `.tpl.php` in particular) hence the current behaviour/bug.

**This behaviour is already fixed and 9.0.2 should arrive soon (few days). In meantime you can fix it manually in few different ways:**

1. You can just rename the file to get rid of such double extension, e.g. make it just `header.php` or `inc.header.php`.
2. Or manually set outer language as HTML in `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Template Data Languages` -- find your file there and set `HTML` in second column.

---

**UPDATE:** (18/08/2015)

PhpStorm v9.0.2 has now been released.

Comment: PhpStorm update 9.0.2 is released and it solves the problem!